# The sum of two geometric distributions with same p

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X and Y be independent random variables, and k is the number of failures before a success

$P(X=k)=P(Y=k)=p(1−p)^k$

How is it possible to arrive at the probability function $Z = X + Y$

$P(Z=z)=(z+1)p^2(1-p)^z$

without using logic? Specifically, where does the z+1 term derive from?

Comment: Sorry, what is $t$?

Comment: That was supposed to be a z, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

We use logic. We are tossing a coin that has probability of head equal to $p$. Let $X$ be the total number of tails up to the first head, and let $Y$ be the number of tails from the first head to the second head. Then $X+Y$ is the total number of tails up to the second head.

Call this number $Z$. Then $Z=z$ if we have exactly $1$ head in the first $z+1$ tosses, and get a head on the $z$-th toss.

The probability of exactly $1$ head in the first $z+1$ tosses is $\binom{z+1}{1}p^1 (1-p)^{z}$. Given that this event has happened, the probability of a head on the $z$-th toss is $p$. Thus
$$\Pr(Z=z)=\binom{z+1}{1}(1-p)^{z}p^2.$$